# Perché la chiamiamo 'macchina'?

Tags: word-usage

Consultando il termine [macchina](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/macchina.shtml) in un dizionario, tra i vari significati si trova: automobile.

> - 1) Congegno meccanico ideato per compiere un lavoro che potenzia quello che può svolgere l'uomo con le sue forze o che trasforma un'energia in un'altra; estens. qualunque congegno la cui natura e funzione è precisata da un complemento.
> - 2) In uso assol., qualsiasi macchina in generale, dispositivo o congegno che compie qlco. meccanicamente e la cui esplicitazione si ricava dal contesto.
> - 3) fig. Usato come termine di confronto per indicare una persona che lavora molto SIN robot: non è un uomo, è una m.
> - 4)  **Per antonomasia, l'automobile** o, anche, altri mezzi di locomozione terrestre, aerea o marittima destinati al trasporto di persone SIN auto: vendere la m.; 
>     l'automobile | posto m., spazio riservato al parcheggio di un'automobile.
> - Etc.

In realtà il termine macchina è molto usato per indicare una vettura, anzi sembra essere  più usato del termine automobile: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guidare%20la%20macchina%2Cguidare%20l%27automobile%2C%20parcheggiare%20la%20macchina%2C%20parcheggiare%20l%27automobile&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cguidare%20la%20macchina%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguidare%20l%27%20automobile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparcheggiare%20la%20macchina%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparcheggiare%20l%27%20automobile%3B%2Cc0).

Gli  inglesi la chiamano 'car' e i francesi 'voiture' (non 'machine'). Perché noi italiani invece la chiamiamo 'macchina'?

Comment: Non risponde esattamente alla domanda, ma potrebbe essere interessante: su [wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile#Etimologia) si legge che "nel linguaggio comune sia scritto che parlato, prevalse il femminile soprattutto perché l'espressione "l'automobile" venne intesa quale sinonimo della più popolare e generica "la macchina". A tale trasformazione linguistica contribuì anche l'autorevole opinione di Gabriele d'Annunzio che, in una lettera inviata nel 1920 al senatore Giovanni Agnelli, si esprimeva a favore della declinazione al femminile del termine."

Comment: In tedesco: _das Auto_ oppure _der Wagen_ (etimologia chiara). Nelle lingue scandinave: _bil[en]_ (da _automobil[en]_) (_en_ è l'articolo determinativo enclitico).

Answer (score 5):

Nello Zingarelli 2010, alla voce "macchina", viene evidenziato che il termine ha, tra gli altri, il significato di automobile per antonomasia: sembrerebbe quindi che, nel linguaggio comune, l'automobile sia ritenuta "La" macchina per eccellenza.

È inoltre interessante sottolineare quanto si può leggere alla [voce "Automobile" su Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile#Etimologia):

> nel linguaggio comune sia scritto che parlato, prevalse il femminile [per la parola automobile]
>   soprattutto perché l'espressione "l'automobile" venne intesa quale
>   sinonimo della più popolare e generica "la macchina". A tale
>   trasformazione linguistica contribuì anche l'autorevole opinione di
>   Gabriele d'Annunzio che, in una lettera inviata nel 1920 al senatore
>   Giovanni Agnelli, si esprimeva a favore della declinazione al
>   femminile del termine.

Comment: Per la precisione, D'Annunzio scrisse: «Mio caro Senatore, in questo momento ritorno dal mio campo di Desenzano, con la Sua macchina che mi sembra risolvere la questione del sesso già dibattuta. L’Automobile è femminile. Questa ha la grazia, la snellezza, la vivacità d’una seduttrice; ha, inoltre, una virtù ignota alle donne: la perfetta obbedienza. Ma, per contro, delle donne ha la disinvolta levità nel superare ogni scabrezza». Ma mi pare che la domanda fosse su perché si usi “macchina”, non “automobile”.

Comment: @DaG grazie per il tuo commento, infatti l'ho scritto come approfondimento a mio avviso interessante

Answer (score 0):

Temo che sia dovuto all'uso comune.

Quanto allo Zingarelli, da un lato fa bene a chiarire che `macchina` è un termine utilizzato - nel gergo comune - in luogo di `automobile`.

Viceversa, così facendo avalla un modo di dire errato (a mio avviso). Un caso analogo è `obiezione` che in alcuni vocabolari viene declinato anche come `obbiezione`, quest'ultimo errato, ma di uso comune come `macchina`.

Comment: In base a cosa consideri “errati” *macchina* nel senso di automobile e *obbiezione*?

Comment: Ho usato l'esempio di _obbiezione_ perché credo possa mettere d'accordo tutti (_obiezione_ è il termine originale, il secondo è stato corretto con la penna rossa per decenni, finché anche chi scrive dizionari ha constatato la sua diffusione). Analogamente per _macchina_: il termine originale è _automobile_, mentre _macchina_ arriva per secondo e - se ha più successo - non significa che sia corretto. Ma non sono un linguista, potrei sbagliare.

Comment: Neanch'io sono un linguista, ma [il sito della Crusca dice](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/obiettivo-obbiettivo-obiezione-obbiezione) «Intendiamoci, le varianti con due b non sono sbagliate, ma sono più lontane dagli originali latini, che erano *obiectare*, *obiectivus*, *obiector*, *obiectio*», mentre su *macchina* francamente non capisco che cosa possa avere di sbagliato (né in che senso *macchina* sia venuta “dopo”, quando precede di circa quattro secoli *automobile*): al massimo è meno precisa.

Comment: Intendevo proprio questo: _macchina_ è un termine generico, può essere riferito a tante cose diverse. Invece _automobile_ è specifico.

Comment: Per essere un po' più costruttivo, una “macchina” è una qualunque struttura in movimento e quindi lo sono i meccanismi teatrali che portavano in scena i personaggi (*Deus ex machina*) e l'enorme torre che viene portata in spalla a Viterbo (la macchina di santa Rosa). Viceversa, sarebbe improprio dire “macchina fotografica”, perché è un apparecchio che sta lì immobile (e se lo muoviamo mentre lo usiamo la foto non viene bene). Si vede che progressivamente l'automobile è stata percepita come “macchina” per eccellenza.

Comment: Sì, concordo con "macchina per eccellenza". Mi piace come spiegazione.

Comment: Perché mai *obbiezione* sarebbe “errato”? Sicuramente *avvallare* lo è, invece. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Perché, volendo usare un'altra frase idiomatica, _obbiezione_ è come un calcio in un orecchio. Almeno, così mi risuona.